# Can I make 3 errors types without if/else with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, renderless-component

Can I make 3 errors types without if/else?

I need to show 3 types of errors (they have different positions):

- common
- errorLogin
- errorPassword

What I have now:
I made a renderless function.
And I see 2 ways:

- use if/else in the template of the component:

  Component.vue

  ```
     <login-error-renderless
       v-if="isError"
       :errorMessage="errorMessage"
       :rowClass="$style.errorLogin"
       :colClass="$style.errorInner"
     >
     </login-error-renderless>
     <login-error-renderless
       v-else-if="isError && messageList[1]"
       :errorMessage="errorMessage"
       :rowClass="$style.errorPassword"
       :colClass="$style.errorInner"
     >
     </login-error-renderless>
     <login-error-renderless
       v-else-if="isError && !messageList[0] && !messageList[1]"
       :errorMessage="errorMessage"
       :rowClass="$style.errorWrap"
       :colClass="$style.errorInner"
     >
     </login-error-renderless>
  ```

RenderlessFunction.vue

```
 return h('div', { attrs: { class: this.rowClass } }, [
          h('div', { attrs: { class: this.colClass} }, [
            h('span', {}, this.errorMessage),
        ]),
```

- use if/else in the renderless function (I'm using this now):

Component.vue

```
<login-error-renderless
    v-if="isError"
    :errorMessage="errorMessage"
    :classList="classList"
    :messageList = "messages"
>
</login-error-renderless>
```

Renderless.vue:

```
props: {
    errorMessage: String,
    classList: Object,
    messageList: Array,
  }, 

render(h) {
const createFunction = (rowClass, colClass = this.classList.innerClass) => h('div', { attrs: { class: rowClass } }, [
  h('div', { attrs: { class: colClass } }, [
    h('span', {}, this.errorMessage),
  ]),
]);

if (this.messageList[0] !== undefined) {
  return createFunction(this.classList.errorLogin);
}
if (this.messageList[1] !== undefined) {
  return createFunction(this.classList.errorPassword);
}
return createFunction(this.classList.error);
```

},

Comment: `v-if/v-else` seems pretty useful to me. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: I hate many if/else (and this is the worst practice - to use many if/else where you can don't use it) and that is code repetition. point 2 (in this case) looks mutch better and this's the best what i could think of. 
But I want to know other ways if they exist

Comment: I can only think of [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) with the example from the documentation. Every `if-case` is a `tab`.

Comment: not is this case:)